# Return ternary condition ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to return the ternary condition in the success case. Currently:

```
count = QuoteRequest.open.count
@quote_request_count = count > 0 ? count : nil
```

I would like something like this:

```
count = QuoteRequest.open.count > 0 ? QuoteRequest.open.count :nil
@quote_request_count = count > 0 ? count : nil
```

This would however execute the ActiveRecord statement twice, I would like to only execute it once. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Why do you have to assign `nil` in the first place, what's wrong with `0`?

Comment: Why use a ternary? They usually result in less readable code and don't improve speed. Avoiding them is usually recommended.

Comment: @theTinMan: In this case, it's quite simple. When to use ternary if not in cases like this?

Comment: Worse than executing the ActiveRecord statement twice (and it's not the case, since query results are cached), your code will crash when `QuoteRequest.open.count` equals 0.

Comment: Re: when to use ternary, "[Avoid the ternary operator (?:) except in cases where all expressions are extremely trivial.](https://github.com/styleguide/ruby)". Ternary operators are one of the most confusing operators to inexperienced programmers; We see questions here asking what `?:` means regularly. If we are returning a base type, like a short string or a Boolean or Fixnum then they are obviously OK. Usability diminishes with more complex return values. I'd write the answer with a simple if/then/else for readability.

Comment: I don't want to have double checks for if value && value > 0 in the views.

@theTinMan thanks, I agree it makes sense from a readability point of view to not use ternary in this case.

Comment: On our team at work, during code reviews, I often ask, "what is more readable?" I want code that we can glance at and *know* what it's doing, without puzzling over it, or having to read comments explaining it. The reason is, we don't always get the job of debugging and maintaining our own code, and in a production-is-down situation after midnight, whoever is dealing with it needs to be able to figure it out fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = (tmp = QuoteRequest.open.count) > 0 ? tmp : nil
@quote_request_count = count > 0 ? count : nil
```

Is this working ?

Comment: Work or not, it's sacrificing readability and not gaining anything.

Comment: I accept this answer as it is correct. However what @theTinMan sais makes sense.